# Kubernetes - ingress route issue - route across namespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have one master and two worker node kubernetes cluster on `AWS`. And I have two environments (qc and prod) in the cluster and I created two namespaces.
I have the same service running on `qc`and `prod` namespaces.

I have created ingress for both namespaces.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.qc-k8s.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app
        backend:
          serviceName: client-svc
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: qc
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.qc-k8s.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app-qc
        backend:
          serviceName: client-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I have `client-svc` in both `qc` and `prod` namespaces and open the nodeport 80.
Then I created `ELB` service and `daemonset` as below.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
  namespace: deafult
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:ca-central-1:492276880714:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: http
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: deafult
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.6
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            hostPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

When I tried to curl `curl -iv https://gayan.qc-k8s.example.com/app/`. Then Im getting an error.

**2017/06/27 15:43:31 [error] 158#158: *981 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 209.128.50.138, server: gayan.qc-k8s.example.com, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://100.82.2.47:80/app/", host: "gayan.qc-k8s.example.com"
209.128.50.138 - [209.128.50.138, 209.128.50.138] - - [27/Jun/2017:15:43:31 +0000] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 500 193 "-" "curl/7.51.0" 198 0.014 100.82.2.47:80, 100.96.2.48:80 0, 193 0.001, 0.013 502, 500**

If I curl `curl -iv https://gayan.qc-k8s.example.com/app-qc`, I'm getting the same issue. 
Anyone has experienced this error previously ? any clue to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088

An example, from a real document we use:

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress
    namespace: dev-1
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: api-gateway-dev-1.faceit.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api-gateway
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
    - host: api-shop-dev-1.faceit.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api-shop
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
    - host: api-search-dev-1.faceit.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api-search
            servicePort: 8080
          path: /
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - api-gateway-dev-1.faceit.com
      - api-search-dev-1.faceit.com
      - api-shop-dev-1.faceit.com
      secretName: faceitssl
```

We make one of these for each of our namespaces for each track.

Then, we have a single namespace with an Ingress Controller which runs automatically configured NGINX pods. Another AWS Load balancer points to these pods which run on a NodePort using a DaemonSet to run at most and at least one on every node in our cluster.

As such, the traffic is then routed:

Internet -> AWS ELB -> NGINX (on node) -> Pod

We keep the isolation between namespaces while using Ingresses as they were intended. It's not correct or even sensible to use one ingress to hit multiple namespaces. It just doesn't make sense, given how they are designed. The solution is to use one ingress per each namespace with a cluster-scope ingress controller which actually does the routing.